# Stumped on recursive solution

Tags: c#, string, recursion

I was working through some problems on http://codingbat.com/prob/p117334
The iterative solution is straightforward but my attempts at a recursive
solution have me tied up in knots. I'm trying to get a better handle on recursion but this one has me stumped.

I thought maybe this was a problem that could not be solved with recursion
but further research indicates that anything solved iteratively can also be solved recursively.

Given a non-empty string like "Code" return a string like "CCoCodCode".

LINQPad template:

```
void Main()
{
    StringSplosion("Code").Dump(); // "CCoCodCode"
    StringSplosion("abc").Dump(); // "aababc"
    StringSplosion("ab").Dump(); // "aab"   
}

static string StringSplosion(string s) {

}
```

Comment: Show your iterative solution and your attempts at recursion and perhaps explain what exactly is stumping you

Comment: Hints... Define your base case.. `s` has length <= 1,in which case you return `s`. Ok now what? If it's longer you *either* prefix or suffix `s` with the result of calling your method passing some substring of `s`. Can you find that substring? Do you prefix or suffix?

Comment: I was close:
`static string StringSplosion(string s) {

 if (s.Length <= 1) {
  return s;
 }
 
 return s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) + StringSplosion(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
 
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can see the solution is a progressing series of a substring of one character, then a substring of two characters, then three, etc. A recursive way to look at it could be something like this:

1. A StringSplosion of an empty string is an empty string (stop condition)
2. A StringSplosion of a non-empty string is the concatenation of a StringSplosion of the string without its last character and the string itself.

or, in code:

```
public static String StringSplosion(String str) {
  if (str.Length == 0) {
    return str;
  }
  return StringSplosion(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)) + str;
}
```

Comment: I'd have gone with `if (str.Length <= 1) return str` ultimately the same thing though

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying comments. I almost had it.

Comment: I couldn't get my head around the recursive call being distinct from the + str; I thought the string would keep getting larger and hence never stop.